# How to install NodeJS and NPM on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, software-installation, nodejs, npm

How to install NodeJS and NPM on Ubuntu 18.04?

1) I'm wrong, I add the referenciel 11 while I want the version 10 LTS. How can I change that ?

2) Can not install NodeJS and NPM. THERE are errors ?

```
ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 11.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                        
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                          
Hit:4 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hda-me/nginx-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                 
Hit:6 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                
Hit:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x bionic InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:8 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                              
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                          
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                  
Hit:11 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease               
Hit:12 https://deb.goaccess.io bionic InRelease                                     
Reading package lists... Done                      

## Confirming "bionic" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x/dists/bionic/Release'

## Adding the NodeSource signing key to your keyring...

+ curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
OK

## Creating apt sources list file for the NodeSource Node.js 11.x repo...

+ echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x bionic main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
+ echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x bionic main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

## Running `apt-get update` for you...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                          
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                     
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hda-me/nginx-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                 
Get:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x bionic InRelease [4,584 B]                                                                      
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                          
Hit:7 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease                                                                       
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                    
Hit:9 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                        
Hit:10 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                      
Hit:11 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                            
Hit:12 https://deb.goaccess.io bionic InRelease                                                                                           
Get:13 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x bionic/main amd64 Packages [768 B]
Fetched 5,352 B in 3s (1,967 B/s)                           
Reading package lists... Done

## Run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 11.x and npm
## You may also need development tools to build native addons:
     sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make
## To install the Yarn package manager, run:
     curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
     echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
     sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn


ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ nano /etc/apt/sources.list
ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ sudo apt install nodejs npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Conflicts: npm
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```